# Number of Chess Games Possible: Parity Discussion

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle, chessboard

Chess is an incredibly intricate game, offering an immense number of moves and combinations. Due to this complexity, determining the precise count of legal chess games poses a significant challenge. As of my knowledge, the total number of possible legal chess games remains unknown due to the vast array of potential moves and positions that can emerge during gameplay.

However, I've been pondering an intriguing question: Can we establish whether the total number of legal chess games is odd or even? It's a captivating puzzle that has captured my attention. I've given it considerable thought, but I must admit that I'm still uncertain about the parity of the total number of games. Can anyone direct me how to approach this?

Comment: The odds are even !$\;\;$ :)

Comment: @trueblueanil very punny! :)

Comment: How many different game prefixes are there where the knights move around a whole bunch and then return to their starting squares?  If that number is even, then the number of distinct games is even. If it's odd, then that's not enough to know.

Comment: @DanUznanski, the problem here is 3-fold repetition rule.

Comment: I'd try answering simpler questions first: the parity of games with missing pieces, eg, 2 kings, a king and a knight, etc.

Comment: @GraduateStudent Threefold repitition and fivefold repitition shouldn't be too much of an issue with the knight-moving approach, because, once a pawn advances, we will be no longer able to repeat the starting position again. However, the fifty-move rule and the seventy-five move rule do pose challenges to the knight-moving approach, because not every knight-moving prefix has the same number of moves.

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, the fifty-move and seventy-five-move rules shouldn't be too much of an issue either, because the count is reset once a pawn moves.

Comment: @DanUznanski Could you explain why that would be the case? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @Enforce If there's an even number of prefixes that return to the starting position, then we can "pair up" each game starting with prefix $p_{2n}$ with a game starting with prefix $p_{2n+1}$ that plays out exactly like it after the return to the starting position.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_number

Comment: 1. The seventy-five move-rule does no longer apply. 2. The number of games can only be estimated. It is incredibly difficult to count them exactly 3. Even the number of legal positions can only be estimated.